# Android 4.1.2 doesn't play videos stored in cache folder - permission denied

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, permission-denied

I'm stuck with error "Permission denied" when I'm trying to load video file from application cache folder. I tried many examples and suggestions from here and other Internet sources but nothing help so far.

I'm using Apache Flex 4.13.0 and Air 14.0. Files are downloaded from Internet in to the app cache folder "data/data/application_name/cache. I've checked destination using application debbugable=true and adb shell all files are in place. Second part off application is Air native extension which is using TextureView and MediaPlayer to play videos. Application works fine on Nexus 4 and Samsung Galaxy S4 (Both Android 4.4.2) but doesn't want to play on Samsung Duos Model number: GT-S6810P, Android Version: 4.1.2, Air: 14.0.0.179. The logcat says:

```
09-10 11:52:38.536: D/InlineVideoContext(28275): MediaPlayer is about to set DataSource!
09-10 11:52:38.736: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(1715): refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
09-10 11:52:38.886: I/application_name(28275): LogViewingSession is finished!
09-10 11:52:38.896: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): Client(34) constructor
09-10 11:52:38.896: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): Create new client(34) from pid 28275, uid 10121, 
09-10 11:52:38.896: D/MediaPlayer(28275): player=0x0x52530c10, getpid()=28275, this=0x0x532ab868, mAudioSessionId=80
09-10 11:52:38.906: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): player type = 3
09-10 11:52:38.906: V/MediaPlayerService(1238):  create StagefrightPlayer
09-10 11:52:38.926: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): setDefault
09-10 11:52:38.926: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): constructor
09-10 11:52:38.936: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): AwesomePlayer: AWESOME SEEK LATENESS 500000 ms
09-10 11:52:38.936: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): AwesomePlayer: AWESOME SEEK OPTION <SEEK_VIDEO_ONLY>
09-10 11:52:38.936: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): AwesomePlayer: AWESOME LATENESS 40000 ms
09-10 11:52:38.936: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): setDefault
09-10 11:52:38.936: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): reset
09-10 11:52:38.936: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): cancel player events
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/StagefrightPlayer(1238): StagefrightPlayer
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): setListener
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/StagefrightPlayer(1238): initCheck
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): AwesomePlayer running on behalf of uid 10121
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/AudioSink(1238): AudioOutput(80)
09-10 11:52:38.946: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): cancel player events
09-10 11:52:38.946: I/AwesomePlayer(1238): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayerService(1238):  setDataSource
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): [34] getParameter(1700)
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayer(28275): setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): [34] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x4208d9c8)
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/StagefrightPlayer(1238): setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayer(28275): prepare
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): [34] setAudioStreamType(3)
09-10 11:52:38.946: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): [34] prepareAsync
09-10 11:52:38.956: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): prepareAsync
09-10 11:52:38.966: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): onPrepareAsyncEvent
09-10 11:52:38.966: E/(1238): Failed to open file '/data/data/application_name/cache/5292b615-5a22-4330-87a2-a35500cde0ce/sections/0a52aff3-aef8-4af0-becc-a39300fce589/6b83d738-f6eb-4fd9-8d58-a39300fce5aa/0fb55f28-16a5-4f55-9d6a-a39300fce59e.mp4'. (Permission denied)
09-10 11:52:38.966: E/AwesomePlayer(1238): cannot create dataSource
09-10 11:52:38.966: W/AwesomePlayer(1238): onPrepareAsyncEvent() finishSetDataSource_l error(-2147483648)
09-10 11:52:38.966: W/AwesomePlayer(1238): abortPrepare() mIsAsyncPrepare (1), err (-2147483648)
09-10 11:52:38.966: V/AwesomePlayer(1238): notifyListner_l() msg (100-MEDIA_ERROR), ext1 (1), ext2 (-2147483648)
09-10 11:52:38.966: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): [34] notify (0x42214080)
09-10 11:52:38.966: V/MediaPlayerService(1238): [34] notify (0x42214080, 100, 1, -2147483648)
09-10 11:52:38.966: V/MediaPlayer(28275): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
09-10 11:52:38.976: E/MediaPlayer(28275): error (1, -2147483648)
09-10 11:52:38.976: V/MediaPlayer(28275): signal application thread
09-10 11:52:38.976: V/MediaPlayer(28275): prepare complete - status=1
09-10 11:52:38.976: E/InlineVideoContext(28275): Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

setting dataSource:

```
if(_mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    dispatchStatusEventAsync("PLAYBACK_DID_FINISH",  Integer.toString(_currentPosition));

                _currentPosition = 0;
                _mediaPlayer.stop();
                _mediaPlayer.reset();

                Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer is about to set DataSource!");


                _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(_path);
                _mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

I tried to use URI, FileDescriptor, File.getAbsolutePath and just String path which is working fine on Nexus 4 and Samsung Galaxy S4.

Does anyone came across such problem and was lucky to solve it? Any help is appreciated

Comment: It looks like I should use FileInputStream and FileDescriptor but then logcat says: 09-10 16:12:18.701: E/InlineVideoContext(2444): /file:/data/data/application_name/cache/5292b615-5a22-4330-87a2-a35500cde0ce/sections/0a52aff3-aef8-4af0-becc-a39300fce589/6b83d738-f6eb-4fd9-8d58-a39300fce5aa/0fb55f28-16a5-4f55-9d6a-a39300fce59e.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Finnaly I found the problem. I was sending wrong file path to ANE. The path has to be absolute path "data/data/app_name/cache" and not  "file://data/data/app_name/cache". However Android 4.4.2 is still fine with path starting with "file://".